# I get a [DEBUG] worker: SIGWINCH ignored error when publishing my flask application with Guncorn3

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I made a little app with flask. I run the app on my ubuntu system as python3 app.py and everything works fine. I wanted to publish the app with gunicorn, but some functions also get errors. I looked at the error logs and [DEBUG] worker: SIGWINCH ignored. I get this error. The reason for the error is I put python pexpect module

```
def botbaslatma():
    child = pexpect.spawn('screen -S idle python3 bot_dosyalari/{}'.format(session["username"]+".py"))
    i=child.expect(['Enter 2FA code: ',"Invalid password for '{}'. Enter password: ".format(session["username"]),pexpect.EOF])
    if i==0:
        child.sendline(Guard)
        k=child.expect(['Logged on as:','Incorrect code. Enter 2FA code: ',pexpect.EOF])
        if k==0:
            cursor=Mysql.connection.cursor()
            sorgu='UPDATE sxxxxeri SET status="Aktif" WHERE stxxxxci="{}" '.format(session["username"])
            cursor.execute(sorgu)
            Mysql.connection.commit()
            cursor.close()
            child.close()
            flash("Done","success")
            return redirect(url_for("xontrolxxxx",_external=True))
        elif k==1:
            cursor=Mysql.connection.cursor()
            sorgu='UPDATE sxxxleri SET status="Bexxxyor" WHERE steaxxxici="{}" '.format(session["username"])
            cursor.execute(sorgu)
            Mysql.connection.commit()
            cursor.close()
            child.close()
            flash("Wrong passwd","danger")
            return redirect(url_for("xontrolxxxx",_external=True))
        elif i==2:#timeout
            flash("Timeout","danger")
            child.close()
            durdurma()
            return redirect(url_for("xontrolxxxx",_external=True))
    elif i==1:
        child.close()
        durdurma()
        flash("Wrong passwd","danger")
        return redirect(url_for("xontrolxxxx",_external=True))
    elif i==2:
        child.close()
        flash("Timeout","danger")
        return redirect(url_for("xontrolxxxx",_external=True))
    return render_template("botxxxx.html",form=form)

#Always enters pexpect.EOF control i==2
```

######Gunicorn3 file

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn service
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/root/flaskapp
ExecStart=/usr/bin/gunicorn3 --workers 3 --bind unix:flaskapp.sock -m 007 app:app --timeout 300 --config /root/flaskapp/gunicorn.conf.py
```

#Gunicorn3 Error log *************

```
[2020-07-03 15:38:55 +0200] [14261] [DEBUG] Current configuration:
  config: /root/flaskapp/gunicorn.conf.py
  bind: ['unix:flaskapp.sock']
  backlog: 2048
  workers: 3
  worker_class: sync
  threads: 1
  worker_connections: 1000
  max_requests: 0
  max_requests_jitter: 0
  timeout: 300
  graceful_timeout: 30
  keepalive: 2
  limit_request_line: 4094
  limit_request_fields: 100
  limit_request_field_size: 8190
  reload: False
  reload_engine: auto
  spew: False
  check_config: False
  preload_app: False
  sendfile: None
  chdir: /root/flaskapp
  daemon: False
  raw_env: []
  pidfile: None
  worker_tmp_dir: None
  user: 0
  group: 33
  umask: 7
  initgroups: False
  tmp_upload_dir: None
  secure_scheme_headers: {'X-FORWARDED-PROTOCOL': 'ssl', 'X-FORWARDED-PROTO': 'https', 'X-FORWARDED-SSL': 'on'}
  forwarded_allow_ips: ['127.0.0.1']
  accesslog: /root/flaskapp/flaskapp.gunicorn.access
  access_log_format: %(h)s %(l)s %(u)s %(t)s "%(r)s" %(s)s %(b)s "%(f)s" "%(a)s"
  errorlog: /root/flaskapp/flaskapp.gunicorn.error
  loglevel: debug
  capture_output: False
  logger_class: gunicorn.glogging.Logger
  logconfig: None
  syslog_addr: udp://localhost:xxx
  syslog: False
  syslog_prefix: None
  syslog_facility: user
  enable_stdio_inheritance: False
  statsd_host: None
  statsd_prefix: 
  proc_name: None
  default_proc_name: app:app
  pythonpath: None
  paste: None
  on_starting: <function OnStarting.on_starting at 0x7f66cff9c048>
  on_reload: <function OnReload.on_reload at 0x7f66cff9c1e0>
  when_ready: <function WhenReady.when_ready at 0x7f66cff9c378>
  pre_fork: <function Prefork.pre_fork at 0x7f66cff9c510>
  post_fork: <function Postfork.post_fork at 0x7f66cff9c6a8>
  post_worker_init: <function PostWorkerInit.post_worker_init at 0x7f66cff9c840>
  worker_int: <function WorkerInt.worker_int at 0x7f66cff9c9d8>
  worker_abort: <function WorkerAbort.worker_abort at 0x7f66cff9cb70>
  pre_exec: <function PreExec.pre_exec at 0x7f66cff9cd08>
  pre_request: <function PreRequest.pre_request at 0x7f66cff9cea0>
  post_request: <function PostRequest.post_request at 0x7f66cff9f048>
  child_exit: <function ChildExit.child_exit at 0x7f66cff9f1e0>
  worker_exit: <function WorkerExit.worker_exit at 0x7f66cff9f378>
  nworkers_changed: <function NumWorkersChanged.nworkers_changed at 0x7f66cff9f510>
  on_exit: <function OnExit.on_exit at 0x7f66cff9f6a8>
  proxy_protocol: False
  proxy_allow_ips: ['127.0.0.1']
  keyfile: None
  certfile: None
  ssl_version: 2
  cert_reqs: 0
  ca_certs: None
  suppress_ragged_eofs: True
  do_handshake_on_connect: False
  ciphers: TLSv1
  raw_paste_global_conf: []
[2020-07-03 15:38:55 +0200] [14261] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
[2020-07-03 15:38:55 +0200] [14261] [DEBUG] Arbiter booted
[2020-07-03 15:38:55 +0200] [14261] [INFO] Listening at: unix:flaskapp.sock (14261)
[2020-07-03 15:38:55 +0200] [14261] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2020-07-03 15:38:55 +0200] [14282] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 14282
[2020-07-03 15:38:55 +0200] [14285] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 14285
[2020-07-03 15:38:55 +0200] [14286] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 14286
[2020-07-03 15:38:55 +0200] [14261] [DEBUG] 3 workers
[2020-07-03 15:39:03 +0200] [14285] [DEBUG] GET /kontrolpaneli
[2020-07-03 15:39:03 +0200] [14285] [DEBUG] GET /login
[2020-07-03 15:39:13 +0200] [14282] [DEBUG] POST /login
[2020-07-03 15:39:13 +0200] [14285] [DEBUG] GET /
[2020-07-03 15:39:17 +0200] [14286] [DEBUG] GET /kontrolpaneli
[2020-07-03 15:39:19 +0200] [14285] [DEBUG] GET /botbaslatma
[2020-07-03 15:39:43 +0200] [14285] [DEBUG] POST /botbaslatma
[2020-07-03 15:39:43 +0200] [14412] [DEBUG] worker: SIGWINCH ignored. **here it is**
[2020-07-03 15:39:43 +0200] [14285] [DEBUG] GET /kontrolpaneli
```

Comment: You may need to sanitise your inputs. Looks like logging in with a username like "; cat /etc/passwd #" would lead to remote code execution as root. Also if you want to run your app as root, at least add a few security flags in your Gunicorn  service file. Under the [Service] section, try adding ProtectSystem=full, ProtectHome=true, ProtectKernelModules=true, ProtectControlGroups=true

Answer (score 3):

This message is harmless. The signal SIGWINCH marks that the terminal window was resized. There is no real terminal under which your app runs, so that seems normal. It is probably produced by screen.

Your code is **very** weird. Rather than creating a terminal through screen and driving a python command line application through pexpect, the normal approach would be to call bot_dosyalari functions directly. However, it should work.

Additionally, you shouldn't be runnning a web application as root. I guess you did that because www-data didn't have access to `/root/flaskapp`, but the solution is to set the permissions right (probably moving it to e.g. `/var/www/flaskapp` at the same time), not to change the webapp user.